# Plotting with Octave and Matplotlib Broken on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7, amd-graphics, octave, matplotlib

I'm having a problem using plot commands using python-matplotlib and Octave ever since I installed Octave.

Prior to installing Octave v4.0.2, I was able to plot with Matplotlib v. 1.5.1 just fine. Upon installing Octave, I cannot plot in Octave or Matplotlib. Instead, the script hangs at the line where the plot command is called.

Purging Octave and its dependencies does not fix the ability to plot with Matplotlib. Instead, I have to purge both Octave and my entire Python2.7 installation and reinstall Python2.7.

I am using two seperate computers which have two different hardware setups  and the same exact OS and Kernel version. On one, everything works fine (plotting with both Matplotlib and Octave), the other has the problems described above. Therefore, I'm wondering if it's hardware or graphics driver related?

The computer that it works on has NVidia graphics. The computer that is having issues has Radeon graphics. Both computers have very new hardware.

Anybody have ideas on what is causing my issue? I am happy to provide any details necessary to help out.

Thanks!